# How can ping/ tracepath derive the path MTU info?

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute, mtu

How exactly do ping and tracepath manage to obtain info on MTU?

Comment: As per https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask _You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path MTU Discovery is an old idea and it's something your network stack automatically does for you on every connection, because sending full-sized frames without fragmentation is more efficient that requiring fragmentation.

Path MTU Discovery is done by sending large packets with the "Don't Fragment" bit set, and if any hop's router sends back the ICMP error message "Destination Unreachable: Fragmentation Required but 'Don't Fragment' bit set", it should also indicate what its MTU is.